# How to share Text between app users after sharing on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, share, facebook-share

My application is an app for making a travel schedule.
I want to make the app that shares user's schedules.
For this, I tried to simply share text between app users.

Let me explain the steps.

1. One user shares the app on Facebook to the other. When he shares the app, Text "abc" should be included, not on Facebook, but on the app.

(And I already made Textview to see if it can be sent.)

2. The other user opens the app on Facebook. Then Text "abc" should be seen on Textview.

I don't even know what keyword I should search. 
I tried to use 'intent' and 'action.SEND'. But it doesn't work.

Could you please let me know the steps to do the above function?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do it by handling online database and apropriate api can be used for this kind of logic

Comment: You seem to be very new to this. Watch some tutorials for a better understanding! :)

Comment: What would this look like (screenshots)? You should read platform policy, especially this: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill. It sounds like you may be prefilling.